# Getting boolean columns based on value presence in other columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, boolean

I have this table:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': ['a', 'e', 'a', 'e'], 
                         'col2': ['e', 'a', 'c', 'b'], 
                         'col3': ['c', 'b', 'b', 'a']},
                        index=pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], name='index'))
```

| index | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | e | c |
| 2 | e | a | b |
| 3 | a | c | b |
| 4 | e | b | a |

and this list:

```
all_vals = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' 'f']
```

How do I make boolean columns from `df1` such that it includes all columns from the `all_vals` list, even if the value is not in `df1`?

| index | a | b | c | d | e | f |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |
| 2 | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |
| 3 | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 4 | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all_vals to check if the value exists and create new column

```
for val in all_vals:
    df1[val] = (df1 == val).any(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with aggregate max per columns and [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df1 = (pd.get_dummies(df1, dtype=bool, prefix='', prefix_sep='')
         .groupby(axis=1, level=0).max()
         .reindex(all_vals, axis=1, fill_value=False))
print (df1)
          a      b      c      d      e      f
index                                         
1      True  False   True  False   True  False
2      True   True  False  False   True  False
3      True   True   True  False  False  False
4      True   True  False  False   True  False
```